# Error with PHP session declaration

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I have a problem with a file that involves session in PHP.

I have the following two php files:

**confirm_save.php**

```
<?php
include("confirm.php");
$_SESSION = array();
$token = $_SESSION['logout'];


if ($token && $_POST['token']==$token) {

    if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])) {
        setcookie("id", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
        setcookie("user", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
        setcookie("pass", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
    }
    // Destroy the session variables
    session_destroy();
    /*// Double check to see if their sessions exists
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header("location: message.php?msg=Error:_Logout_Failed");
    } else {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }*/ 
    header("location: index.php");
}
else {
    // log potential CSRF attack.
}
    unset($_SESSION["logout"]);
?>
```

Then, I have the **confirm.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$token= md5(uniqid());
$_SESSION['logout'] = $token;
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="confirm_save.php">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
Do you really want to log out?
<input type="submit" value=" Yes " />
<input type="button" value=" No " onclick="history.go(-1);" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

After clicking "yes" in confirm.php, I get the following error:

> Undefined index: logout in C:\wamp\www\confirm_save.php on line 4

Line 4 is

```
$token = $_SESSION['logout'];
```

I really do not know what the error may be.

Comment: 1) it is not an error, just a notice.  2) it tells you that there is no element with key `logout` in array `$_SESSION`. And this happens because at first you are emptying the array `$_SESSION = array();` and at the next line are trying to access non-existing element in it
 `$token = $_SESSION['logout'];` What is the purpose of these actions?

Comment: Simple answer. The value of 'logout' doesn't exist in your $_SESSION array

Comment: hint: You can combine `isset()` : `isset($_COOKIE["id"], $_COOKIE["user"], $_COOKIE["pass"])`

Comment: @Cheery you can put your comment as answer.

Comment: $_SESSION = array(); this statement clearing your session data

Comment: @Raptor this topic is not so interesting to put an answer in it. Comments are enough )

Comment: I wonder why you could post such much code to describe this problem? If I asked this question, I would just stop at the line `$token = $_SESSION['logout'];` and also include the error description. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You empty your $_SESSION by

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

and then try to fill $token

```
$token = $_SESSION['logout'];
```

with no value.

There shouldn't be a reason to empty $_SESSION, nor to define $token as you include confirm.php which also includes your $token with value

**EDIT**

Don't include confirm.php

But do:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $token = $_SESSION['logout'];
    if ($_POST['token']==$token) {
```

...

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean, but when I remove the line $_SESSION = array(); nothing happens, at all. It seems like I never enter the if-sentence in confirm_save.php...

Comment: This is because you set a new $token at the beginning of every call of confirm_save.php. So the token will never match $_POST['token']

Comment: I did this, just before you wrote and was going to reply to my question later. It works beatifully. The clock was 0530 in the morning here so I wanted to have some hours of sleep first. :)

Answer (score 3):

On line 3 you set `$_SESSION` to an empty array, meaning that `$_SESSION['logout']` doesn't exist;

```
$_SESSION = array();
$token = $_SESSION['logout'];
```

I can't see a reason why you would want to empty the array, so you can remove that line.

You don't need the second line anyway. `$token` will be available as set in confirm.php.